# Не отображаются динамические picturebox со случайными координатами

Tags: c#, picturebox

Не появляются на форме picturebox-ы. Если после каждого добавления пикчебокса вызывать messagebox, или код функции random_points() вставить в обработчик события timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e), то всё прорисовывается. Что нужно поправить?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Генерация_точек
{
public partial class MajorForm : Form
{
    int n = 0;
    PictureBox[] points = new PictureBox[65];
    private Point generateXY()
    {
        int X, Y;
        Random r = new Random();
        X = r.Next(0, this.Width);
        Y = r.Next(0, this.Height);
        return new Point(X, Y);
    }
    public void random_points()
    {
        while (n < 65)
        {

            points[n] = new PictureBox
            {
                BackColor = Color.Blue,
                Size = new Size(10, 10),
                Visible = true,
                Location = generateXY(),
            };
            points[n].Show();
            this.Controls.Add(points[n]);
            points[n].Refresh();
            n++;
        }
        this.Refresh();
    }

    public MajorForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Stop();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void MajorForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        random_points();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Нужно вызов `random_points()` перенести в обработчик события `Form.Load`

Comment: Обновите код в вопросе

Comment: Поправил, ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите создания рандомизатора `new Random()` за пределы метода генерации.

Всякие `Refresh()` и `Show()` можно убрать.

У меня вот этот код отработал нормально.

```csharp
public partial class MajorForm : Form
{
    PictureBox[] points = new PictureBox[65];
    Random r = new Random();

    private Point generateXY()
    {
        int X = r.Next(0, this.Width);
        int Y = r.Next(0, this.Height);
        return new Point(X, Y);
    }

    public void random_points()
    {
        int n = 0;
        while (n < points.Length)
        {
            points[n] = new PictureBox
            {
                BackColor = Color.Blue,
                Size = new Size(10, 10),
                Visible = true,
                Location = generateXY(),
            };
            Controls.Add(points[n]);
            n++;
        }
    }

    public MajorForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MajorForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        random_points();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!